# Outlook contacts associate with old email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Outlook 2010 on Windows 8.  Getting rid of one email account but want to keep the contacts. How do I associate the contacts with the new email address.

Comment: I was easily able to find this by doing a Google Search: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx I suggest in the future to do rearch on the topic before asking a question considering the number of results I found by searching for `outlook contact export` is sort of funny.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts (as well as Calendar entries and Tasks) in Outlook are not associated with an email address. They are in the data file (.pst) associated with Outlook (or the Exchange server if you are using Exchange) but not the email address you are using.

You can add a new email address and change it to be the default. Then remove the old address. Depending on the type of new email address you connect to and how you connect you may pull in new Contacts (for example Outlook.com) but your old Contacts should not be removed.